# ImportError. cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py) Python 3.8

Tags: python

I have an issue with `from collections import Mapping`. I gooogle it and found a lot of solved issues. And common solution is `from collections.abc import Mapping` 
But in my case it didn't help.
And I don't understand why interpretetor try import from `/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)` but I use python 3.8. I use virtual env with poetry 1.0.9 and python 3.8
On OS (ubuntu) used two versions of python 3.10 and 3.8 and poetry 1.0.9

```
(as-common-iqrqnKMP-py3.8) lev@lev-HP-ProBook-445-G7:~/work_atol/as_common$ make upload
poetry build
Building as-common (2.5.256.3371b1)
 - Building sdist
 - Built as-common-2.5.256.3371b1.tar.gz

 - Building wheel
 - Built as_common-2.5.256.3371b1-py3-none-any.whl
poetry config repositories.atol-pypi "repo_url"
poetry publish -r atol-pypi -u "user" -p "pass"

[ImportError]
cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
make: *** [Makefile:23: upload] Ошибка 1
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the ***full*** error traceback? `from collections.abc import Mapping` should work just fine

Comment: @Tomerikoo Updated ask

Comment: The error shows that the import is `from collections` and not `collections.abc`. I can't tell where that import is coming from but if it's not your code, the only reason to import from `collections` is for a Python version prior to 3.3 (that's when `abc` was moved to a separate sub-module)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you're using wrong syntax in your import statement.

It should be either

> import [module]

or

> from [module] import [function]

Try to do it like this:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Comment: Thks. I edited text in my question. But in code used correct sintax `from collections.abc import Mapping`